# How does infinispan know that it have to take the changes from delta aware object

Tags: caching, replication, infinispan

We are using infinispan and in our system we have a big object in which we have to push small changes per transaction. I have implemented the DeltaAware interface for this object and also the Delta. The problem i am facing is that the changes are not getting propagated to other nodes and only the initial object state is prapogated to other nodes. Also the delta and commit methods are not called on the big object which implements DeltaAware. Do i need to register this object somewhere other than simply putting it in the cache ?

Thanks

Comment: This was cross-posted to https://community.jboss.org/message/729328#729328

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better if you simply use an [AtomicHashMap](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/atomic/AtomicHashMap.html), which is a construction within Infinispan. This allows you to group a series of key/value pairs as a single value. Infinispan can detect changes in this AtomicHashMap because it implements the DeltaAware interface. AHM is a higher level construct than DeltaAware, and one that probably suits you better.

To give you an example where AtomicHashMaps are used, they're heavily used by JBoss AS7 HTTP session replication, where each session id is mapped to an AtomicHashMap. This means that we can detect when individual session data changes and only replicate that.

Cheers,
Galder

Comment: Thanks for the response.
We tried using AHM but some how the performance was not that great thats when we thought of implementing our own DeltaAware object. 
I am having distributed cache over 2 machine. while putting data directly in cache we get an average time of 72ms per transaction with 10 puts in a single transaction while when we did the same thing except that instead of putting it in cache directly we used AHM, it took an average of 508ms per transaction with the same key and value size(both strings) and 10puts per transaction.
Is there a way by which i can improve AHM performance?

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in https://community.jboss.org/message/729328#729328